# AngularJS ng-repeat duplicated error, when search is fired

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a listing using `ng-repeat` with a search for two available parameters (month and state).

If I make a search, I get a ng-repeat error found duplicates.

Can not understand why if **in both cases the JSON data have the same structure** (just the values will change).

I have these ng-repeats: `item in data` and nested inside : `uniqueitem in item`

I've tried to use `track by $index` but it loops for every single character, and for item.index or item.label1 but triggers the found duplicates erros again.

Here is my loop using ng-repeat.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in data"> 
    <tr ng-repeat="uniqueitem in item">
        <td>
           {{uniqueitem.label1 | number}} 
        </td>
        <td>
           {{uniqueitem.label2 | number}} 
        </td>
```

My JSON has this structure :

```
[
  {
    "index": 0,
    "label1": "Initials",
    "label2": "2",
    "label3": "18",
    "label4": "12",
    "label5": 150,
    "label6": "30",
    "label7": 60,
    "label5A": "v",
    "label7A": "r"
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "label1": "Others",
    "label2": 5485,
    "label3": 27289,
    "label4": 37776,
    "label5": 72.23,
    "label6": 91949,
    "label7": 29.67,
    "label5A": "r",
    "label7A": "r"
  },
  ....
  ]
```

Comment: Just curious, why is there an `index` property on one object but an `indice` property on the other?

Comment: i am not native english speaker so i adapt from portuguese to english just forget to translate ...

Comment: I am using AngularJS version 1.3

Comment: can you replicate the issue in jsfiddle or plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

Just works !

1. Inside 
   `$http.post(ApiEndpoint.url,$scope.formData).success(function(data) {`
2. Instead of this line :
   `$scope.data = JSON.stringify(data);`
3. I add these lines :

   `var acp = {};`
   `acp.resultdata = [ data ];`
   `$scope.data = acp.resultdata;`

I will replicate in a Plunkr, can not say why JSON.stringify causes this behavior.